# Sätze, welche »die« als eindeutiges Personalpronomen enthalten

Tags: pronoun

Auf Wiktionary ist zu lesen, dass das Wort »die« auch als Personalpronomen Verwendung findet, wenn auch nur mündlich und regional, und - wie ich finde - auch ein wenig abwertend: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/die#Pronomen

Es fällt mir aber schwer Beispielsätze zu finden, in denen »die« eindeutig die Funktion eines Personalpronomens hat, also Sätze, in denen dieses Wort nicht auch als Demonstrativpronomen gedeutet werden kann.

Das sind Beispiele, die mir bzw. Wiktionary eingefallen sind:

Nominativ Singular feminin:

> **Die** ist mir vielleicht eine!

Nominativ Plural:

> **Die** sind mir vielleicht welche!

Akkusativ (Singular feminin oder auch Plural):

> Hast du **die** gesehen?

Ersetzt man in diesen Sätzen »die« durch das eindeutige Personalpronomen »sie«, dann ändert sich die Aussage des Satzes nicht (sie wird nur ein wenig höflicher). Folglich hat hier »die« tatsächlich die Funktion eines Personalpronomens.

Aber in all diesen Beispielen kann man »die« auch durch »diese« oder »jene« ersetzen und ändert damit ebenfalls kaum etwas an der Bedeutung des jeweiligen Satzes. »Diese« und »jene« gehen aber nicht mehr als Personalpronomen durch. Beides sind ganz klar Demonstrativpronomen.

Gibt es Sätze, in denen »die« eindeutig ein Personalpronomen ist, das nicht gleichzeitig auch als Demonstrativpronomen gedeutet werden kann? Oder ist es immer so, dass diese Doppeldeutigkeit besteht?

**EDIT:**

Matthias' Kommentar hat mich darauf aufmerksam gemacht, dass man offenbar recht häufig Personalpronomen der dritten Person durch ein Demonstrativpronomen ersetzen kann. Er = dieser; sie = diese, es = dieses, ihm = diesem, ihn = diesen, usw.

> Kennst du Dr. Müller? Ihm verdanke ich meinen Job.
>   Kennst du Dr. Müller? Diesem verdanke ich meinen Job.

Kling antiquiert, aber würde als besonderer Stil durchgehen und vermutlich nicht als Fehler gelten.

Taxonomisch ist aber klar festgelegt, dass er/sie/es zu den Personalpronomen gehören, dieser/diese/dieses aber zu den Demonstrativpronomen.

Bleibt nun die Frage, ob »die« in »Hast du *die* gesehen?« tatsächlich ein Personalpronomen ist, oder doch eher ein Demonstrativpronomen, denn in den »offiziellen« Auflistungen der beiden Wortarten scheint »die« nur bei den Demonstrativpronomen auf, nicht aber bei den Personalpronomen.

Comment: Fallen Dir Sätze ein, in denen Du "er", "sie" oder "es" nicht durch ein Demonstrativpronomen ersetzen könntest?

Comment: Die beiden Quellen, die der Wiktionary-Eintrag als Beleg für die Verwendung als Personalpronomen aufführt, stützen diese Einordnung nicht, sondern unterscheiden nur zwischen der Funktion als Artikel, Relativ- und eben Demonstrativpronomen. Mindestens eine, nämlich das "Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache", ordnet auch ausdrücklich die abwertende Verwendung dem Demonstrativpronomen zu. Wenn wir nun mal annehmen, daß der Verfasser des Wiktionary-Eintrags beim Griff in die Begriffskiste daneben gelangt hat - was bleibt dann noch als Anlaß für diese Frage?

Answer (score 3):

Personalpronomen sind Pronomen, die auf Personen zeigen können, die an der Sprechsituation beteiligt sind oder anderswo schon eingeführt wurden. Das Demonstrativpronomen ist eine Wortart, mit der der Sprecher auf einen Gesprächsgegenstand verweist, auf den man mit dem Finger zeigen kann.<sup>[(1)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personalpronomen)</sup><sup>[(2)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrativpronomen)</sup>

Da man auf alle diese Beteiligten immer "mit dem Finger zeigen kann", sind demzufolge alle Demonstrativpronomen durch Personalpronomen austauschbar.